# Issue on Loading Required ClusterLayer.js With dojo

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have js file like this and I have saved the `ClusterLayer.js` in all directories like

```
root --> ClusterLayer.js
root --> extras/ClusterLayer.js
root -->js/extras/ClusterLayer.js
root -->js/ClusterLayer.js
```

and the file is like

```
    require([
    "esri/map",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/geometry/Geometry",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
    "extras/ClusterLayer",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
    "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
    "dojo/parser",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
    "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",

    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, arrayUtils, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, Geometry, Point, webMercatorUtils, ClusterLayer, Graphic, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, Color, InfoTemplate, HomeButton, OverviewMap,   parser, GraphicsLayer, SpatialReference, PopupTemplate)
```

but still getting error

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Dojo where to find `extras/ClusterLayer`. You do this via `dojoConfig`. From the [clustering sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html), put this before the script tag that references js.arcgis.com to bring in the JS API:

```
    <script>
      // helpful for understanding dojoConfig.packages vs. dojoConfig.paths:
      // http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/06/20/dojo-faq-what-is-the-difference-packages-vs-paths-vs-aliases/
      var dojoConfig = { 
        paths: {
          extras: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/extras"
        }
      };
    </script>
```